# How To Get The Current Date From Device?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate

I am facing a weird problem with NSDate, when I try fetch a date from device, sometimes it shows previous month for some versions

Here is my chunk of code for reference

```
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateF = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]; 
    [dateF setDateFormat:@" dd.MM.yyyy "];  
    NSString *selectedDate = [dateF stringFromDate:date];
```

Any inputs are appreciated, Thank you

Comment: This gave the right result when I just ran it. What do you mean by "some versions?"

Comment: You should set the locale and timezone of your formatter, to be sure it's not taking some weird default.  But that wouldn't account for the month jumping around -- the only logical reason for that would be accidentally specifying "mm" for month rather than "MM".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid later localizing problems you might use NSCalendar and its method `components:fromDate:`

Something like this:

```
NSCalendar * calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents * components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit 
                                            fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSString * stringDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.%d.%d", components.day, components.month, components.year];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
        NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mma dd/MMM"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
NSLog(@"date: %@", dateString);
[dateFormat release];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example by Apple so it looks like you have your upper-case / lower-case right

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd 'at' HH:mm"];
```

Are you sure your device's date is set right? Also have you tried setting the locale of the NSDateFormatter?

EDIT:

To address you question in comments: NSDate is a point in time irrespective of time zones, calendars and so so on. NSCalendar and NSDateFormatter allow you to convert this point in time into a representation that is correct in a given time zone, with a given calendar.